# How can I tell if launchpad is up or down or is having any network issues?

Tags: launchpad

I've not been able to update or add PPAs for the last few hours.

How can I tell what the status of Launchpad.Net is?

Comment: It looks like what you were looking for is now defined here: https://dev.launchpad.net/Maintenance — although even the links there do not really work much. [Mastodon](https://ubuntu.social/@launchpadstatus) seemed to have some recent info, but not really a clear status, more like "we're working on that, expect disruptions.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to determine if launchpad is having any issues is to look at their twitter feed:

- https://twitter.com/launchpadstatus

[image: pic]

Alternatively - have a look at their blog page:

- http://blog.launchpad.net

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the [twitter page](https://twitter.com/launchpadstatus) as mentioned in another answer and their [blog](http://blog.launchpad.net/)

Lauchpad also has an [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) channel on the [freenode server](http://freenode.net/) the channel is **#launchpad**

If you don't have an IRC client you can access it using a normal web browser [here](https://webchat.freenode.net/)

Another place worth a look may be [Ubuntu Discource](http://ubuntu-discourse.org/)